# How to enable Forms Authentication on azure devops server 2019?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

Is there a way to enable Forms Authentication in azure devops server?
I want a login page for user to login or register.
Currently I can login with a browser prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable Forms Authentication here:IIS(Internet Information Services)->Sites->Azure DevOps Server-> Authentication->Forms Authentication.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I did that but still no luck.

Comment: @RezaT1994 You can only login with a browser prompt. If you want to add users to Azure DevOps Server, please add them in Azure DevOps Server Administration console.